# How to give a image name as parameter in insert query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting trouble on how to give image name which is selected from the hardcoded value as below.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Images(Image)", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img;
```

It throws an exception in line one, and it says

> *")" incorrect syntax.*

I just want to put the value `img` as in 3rd line to the `Images` table which has 3 columns `viz Id`, `Name` and `Image`. I want to insert the `image(img)` into `Image` column which is of `image` datatype.

Please help me :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an invalid `INSERT` syntax. try this,

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Images([Image]) VALUES (@img)", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img;
```

one more thing, `img` must be byte array.